# HTML form submit when press enter key

Tags: asp.net, html, forms

In my form, if I click the submit button it should submit. Even if I am in the text field and press the enter key the form should submit. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
<html>
    < body>

    <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
        First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"  /><br />
        Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This behavior has also varied historically by browser with IE being different in some versions as usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. Browsers let forms be submitted by users pressing enter in a text field; it makes many forms more convenient.

Comment: But only (IIRC) if there is at most one submit button.

Answer (score 0):

this is the default behavior of submit button. submit task fire when you press the enter key.
if you do not want that you can prevent that. use below code in the relevant tag for that.

```
event.preventDefault()
```

ex:-

```
onkeydown='if ((event.keyCode == 13 && document.getElementById("field_0").value!="") &&  event.which == 13){   
                document.getElementById("field_1").focus();
                event.preventDefault();
}'
```

Answer (score -1):

As Quentin said that's normal behavior .But if you want to prevent submission after enter key press , you can do it like :

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript"> 
function testForEnter() 
 {    
   if (event.keyCode == 13) 
   {        
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      event.returnValue = false;
  }
} 
</SCRIPT>
```

See [this post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298498) for more detail.

Comment: Ah, the joy of the global `event` object. This is decidedly non-standard and will only work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @user1057697 :  you should accept Quentin answer , as above is a non-standard solution.